# Removing word or character from string followed by space or before space in c#

Tags: c#

I have a string

```
string name = "AL QADEER UR AL REHMAN AL KHALIL UN";
```

How would I remove all characters `AL`, `UR`, `UN` or may be some more like that.

My string should look like this;

**QADEER REHMAN KHALIL**

Currently I am trying do like this;

```
List<string> list = new List<string> { "AL", "UR", "UN" };

foreach (var item in list )

{
    systemName = systemName.Replace(item, "");
}
```

This is also removing `AL` from `KHALIL`, how do I restrict this to not removing a word containg that characters.

Update:
While adding spaces to words in `List`, will only remove words which has space before and after the word. and concatenate UR to following word. 
I am loading List of words which are to be removed from database;

Comment: Use a regex, it's much easier

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti can you suggest please, I am weak in Regex

Comment: @Vulpex I am loading that list from database, and cab be change any time, how do use this in regex when changes occur

Comment: @trighati are those fixed words?

Comment: @trighati if you need to have a variable regex, i'd suggest either loading it from the database or appsettings

Comment: @user5173426 not fixed can be changed

Comment: @trighati okay then, the length would always be 2?

Comment: @user5173426 no, but not be greater than 4

Comment: @trighati okay. one second.

Comment: @Vulpex Your pattern `\b(UR|AL|UN)` will incorrectly replace in `ALIL` (for instance).

Comment: @JohnyL shoot yeah I forgot the second \b. I deleted it now.
Correctly `\b(UR|AL|UN)\b`

Comment: @Vulpex Good ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this please :

```
var name = "AL QADEER UR AL REHMAN AL KHALIL UN";
var list = new List<string> { "AL", "UR", "UN" };
name = string.Join(" ", name.Split(' ').ToList().Except(list));
```

Comment: This is also removing the duplicate words, if they exist for example if name is `AL QADEER QADEER UR AL REHMAN AL KHALIL UN` it is returning only `AL QADEER UR AL REHMAN AL KHALIL UN` one QADEER is removed why ? Except() is taking care of duplicates

Answer (score 3):

```
static void TestRegex()
{
    string name = "AL QADEER UR AL REHMAN AL KHALIL UN";
    // Add other strings you want to remove
    string pattern = @"\b(AL|UR|UN)\b";
    name = Regex.Replace(name, pattern, String.Empty);
    // Remove extra spaces
    name = Regex.Replace(name, @"\s{2,}", " ").Trim();
    Console.WriteLine(name);
}
```

**UPDATE**

You can generate the pattern this way:

```
// Generate pattern
var list = new List<string> { "AL", "UR", "UN" };
string pattern = @"\b(" + String.Join("|", list) + @")\b";
```

Comment: I am loading that list from database, and cab be change any time, how do use this in regex when changes occur

Comment: @trighati you have to specify your question. This is the answer to the question you posted. Changing it later is kind of annoying since the answers now posted won't fit anymore

Comment: `pattern` is a plain string that you can build using whatever is in your database.

Answer (score 1):

```
var words = new[] { "AL", "UR", "UN" };
var arr = systemName.Split(new[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Except(words);
systemName = string.Join(" ", arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to use regular expressions. Having defined list with "prohibited" words, it's enough to iterate over wprds in the sentence to filter, if word is in the list of prohibited words, then exclude it, otherwise, include the word in final string.

Try this:

```
string name = "AL QADEER UR AL REHMAN AL KHALIL UN";
string systemName = "";
List<string> list = new List<string> { "AL", "UR", "UN" };

foreach (var item in name.Split(new char[] { ' ', ',', '.' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
    systemName += list.Contains(item) ? "" : item + " ";
```

Comment: It's terribly slow,  it adds an extra trailing space, it collapses multiple spaces.

Answer (score 1):

*I am loading that list from database, and can be change any time, how do use this in regex when changes occur*

*okay then, the length would always be 2?*

*no, but not be greater than 4*

```
public static void Main()
{
    var input = "AL QADEER UR AL REHMAN AL KHALIL UN AAA BBB";
    Regex re = new Regex(@"\b\w{1,4}\b");
    var result = re.Replace(input, "");
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
QADEER REHMAN KHALIL
```

[dotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/IYEf8W)

Comment: Perhaps add removing double spaces that were created here (/ ?\b\w{1,4}\b ?/ replace with " ")

Comment: will this will remove ALI, ABID too? I don't want to let it remove such words, only my defined words.

Comment: @trighati you said anything <= 4 chars, this is confusing, if you want only the defined words then you can just replace the reg: `Regex re = new Regex(@"\b(AL|UR|UN)\b");`

Answer (score 1):

Pure `LINQ` answer with the help of `EXCEPT`

```
string name = "AL QADEER UR AL REHMAN AL KHALIL UN";
var list = new string[] { "AL", "UR", "UN" };

name = name
   .Split(new string[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
   .Except(list)
   .Aggregate((prev, next) => $"{prev} {next}");
```

OUTPUT: **QADEER REHMAN KHALIL**