# Removing only specific words from string

Tags: c#

**Note:**I have already asked the question regarding this issue, I have't mentioned the issue of duplicate occurrence of words in string which are also being removed.

I have a string lets say `string name = "AL QADEER QADEER UR AL REHMAN AL KHALIL UN";`

I am loading list of those specific words from data to List or any Array.

The way specific string removing is below;

```
var name = "AL QADEER QADEER UR AL REHMAN AL KHALIL UN";
var list = new List<string> { "AL", "UR", "UN" };
name = string.Join(" ", name.Split(' ').ToList().Except(list));
```

issue is that, this is removing specific words including  duplicate entries of words.  Like QADEER is twice in this string, this should not be removed.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific on your requirements? You want to remove the word if it is present in `list`, but only if it does not appear twice in the string? (i.e. is not a duplicate word in the string)

Comment: Is it me, or I saw this question before (today)?

Comment: I just want to remove words from the list only, whatsoever is in the string should remain as it is, even twice or thrice appearance of any word

Comment: @JohnyL actually I did't mentioned that in that question. this is something deifferent

Comment: @trighati _[My](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50208468/removing-word-or-character-from-string-followed-by-space-or-before-space-in-c-sh/50208613#50208613)_ code doesn't delete duplicates. Did you use it?

Comment: @JohnyL Actually, I preferred LINQ than Regex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try:

```
var name = "AL QADEER QADEER UR AL REHMAN AL KHALIL UN";
var list = new List<string> { "AL", "UR", "UN" };
name = string.Join(" ", name.Split(' ').Where(x => !list.Contains(x));
```

When you use `.Except<TSource>` extension method, the duplicates that are not "excepted" get removed so you have only one copy of each.